# The Shahrukh number of an actor is the length of the shortest path between the actor and Shahrukh Khan in the "co-acting" graph

Tags: sql, imdb

[image: 1]

Question:    The Shahrukh number of an actor is the length of the shortest path between the actor and Shahrukh Khan in the "co-acting" graph.
That is, Shahrukh Khan has Shahrukh number 0; all actors who acted in the same film as Shahrukh have Shahrukh number 1; all actors who acted in the same film as some

Answer: For the given question I have written the below query, however the resultant shape of the output is (28081, 1) but the expected is (25698, 1).

Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

```
WITH 
SHAHRUKH_0 AS
(
    SELECT
        TRIM(P.PID) PID
    FROM
        Person P
    WHERE
        Trim(P.Name) like '%Shah%rukh%Khan%'
),
SHAHRUKH_1_MOVIES AS
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        TRIM(MC.MID) MID,
        S0.PID
    FROM
        M_Cast MC,
        SHAHRUKH_0 S0
    WHERE
        TRIM(MC.PID) = S0.PID
),
SHAHRUKH_1_ACTORS AS
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        TRIM(MC.PID) PID
    FROM
        M_Cast MC,
        SHAHRUKH_1_MOVIES S1M
    WHERE
        TRIM(MC.MID) = S1M.MID AND
        TRIM(MC.PID) <> S1M.PID
),
SHAHRUKH_2_MOVIES AS
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        TRIM(MC.MID) MID,
        S1A.PID
    FROM
        M_Cast MC,
        SHAHRUKH_1_ACTORS S1A
    WHERE
        TRIM(MC.PID) = S1A.PID
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    TRIM(MC.PID) PID,
    TRIM(P.Name) ACTOR_NAME
FROM
    Person P,
    M_Cast MC,
    SHAHRUKH_2_MOVIES S2M
WHERE
        TRIM(MC.PID) = TRIM(P.PID) AND
        TRIM(MC.MID) = S2M.MID AND
        TRIM(MC.PID) <> S2M.PID
```

Answer (score 0):

PLS SEND THE CORRECT ANSWER OF SQL QUERY OF IMDB DATA SET